# SharePoint 2013 weird central administration behaviour using browser on client

Tags: 2013

I have developed a SharePoint 2013 server and its placed in Data Center and my user id is farm administrator also. When I take remote session through RDP and bring central administration http://portal.mydomain:5000 and create site collection then can choose different site templates like "Collaboration", "Enterprise", "Publishing" and "Custom" ..also can pull AD users to make site collection administrator.

But from client machine if I bring central admin page using http://portal.mydomain:5000 it does bring central admin page but it does not allow me select site templates other then "Collaboration" and find it disabled. Plus it doesn't bring AD users also so I can create site administrators...

Why is that...

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are issues with Internet Explorer default viewing compatibility. For those who are banging their heads with IE 9/10 ...here is the solution

1. Access your site in Internet Explorer....
2. Press F12 key (developer tools)
3. do settings as below.

[image]